# Xamarin Controller and xib same folder

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I have just inherited a Xamarin project that keeps the Views (.xib) in a separate folder from the controllers. I find it a little difficult to scroll through the left menu and try to match up the nib files to their controller. So I put the nib files right next to the controller cs file and in the same folder that's organized by domain.

My question is, is there a good reason why they were separated out in the first place? I know a typical MVC application will do this but this is a bit different because a nib file needs to declare the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No good reason that I can think of.  It shouldn't matter either way.  It's mainly organizational preference.  I typically like to keep them together as well.